# Extjs Combobox using json

Tags: combobox, extjs

What is the max size for combobox using json? I seem to die at 5000 json elements.

Comment: What do you mean by die?

Comment: Sorry..when I say die I mean that the combo box does not render. I have a 190,000 lines of json that I'm using. When I take 3000 lines as a sample, my combo box works fine...so my only question to the forum is what is the max number of json lines that an extjs combo box can support?

Answer (score 5):

To state the obvious, from a usability standpoint rendering thousands of records into any UI component is completely useless.  No human will be able to make use of that much data.  A better approach would be server-side filtering to fetch a usable subset of the data.  The combo also supports remote paging if that's an option for you -- there's an example of that in the Ext samples.  There's no "built-in" limit to the amount of data that the combo can handle, but there are practical limits to how much data/rendering any page can handle and still be responsive.